# Jinja2 does not show in the webpage correctly

Tags: python, html, css, django, jinja2

Using Django I have to create a basic website to display the elements inside the SQL database on the webpage.
Right now, I have created a basic HTML template to start from there but since I have included the Jinja2 syntax inside the HTML document, it does nto show correclty. It shows all the Jinja2 code there in the browser. If there is another file you need to look at, just ask.

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Book

# Functions to display the webpages using the render function when button clicked
def index(request):
    return render(request, "index.html", {})


def books(request):
    return render(request, "books.html", {'Book': Book})


def about(request):
    return render(request, "about.html", {})
```

**index.html**

```
{ % extends "header.html" % }

{ % block content % }
    <article>Article</article>      
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/books.html">Books</a></li>
            <li><a href="/about.html">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <aside>Aside</aside>
{ % endblock % }
```

**header.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Welcome</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>Header</header>
  <div id="main">
    { % block content % }

    { % endblock % }
  </div>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</body>

</html>
```

**style.css**

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

#main {
    display: flex;
    min-height: calc(100vh - 40vh);
}

#main > article {
    flex: 1;
}

#main > nav,
#main > aside {
    flex: 0 0 20vw;
    background: gray;
}

#main > nav {
    order: -1;
}

header, footer, article, nav, aside {
    padding: 1em;
}

header, footer {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    height: 20vh;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Please include the respective view function from your app's `views.py` file.

Comment: Added views.py @Dauros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `{%` and `%}` markings are [Jinja specific](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/api/#jinja2.Environment) elements, space is not allowed between e.g. `{` and `%`. Just delete the space between them, then Jinja will recognize its block-markings and render your template correctly.